# Can the variation of the repulsive magnetic flux related to the variation of distances between two permanent magnets be measured with a Tesla meter?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I would like to calculate the repulsive force between two permanent magnets in a different variations of distance between the two polarity faces.
Can the different distances associated to different repulsive forces be related to the magnetic field?
Can the magnetic field have a variation when the distance between the magnets change?
Can a tesla meter measure the magnetic field in the space between the two magnets?
Can the repulsive magnetic flux between two permanent magnets be measured with a tesla meter?
Thank you!